# Javascript : getting the display width of text string in a pre container, in em

Tags: javascript, html

Add non monospace font, tab space in  container, etc...

So how does one derive the width of a text string to be displayed in the container... in em (not px).

This can be useful on devices / website that change the font often. Hence there is no need to "redraw" the size (using the insert, measure, remove) method on every re-size. Some of which has no event to trigger/watch.

Manually using em work so far... the problem is making it automatic. As even jQuery.width()  returns its result in px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect, but gets the job done (somewhat) [uses jQuery]

```
// [div] : a dom node to test insertion of string (inherits its css prop too)
// [str] : the string to test against
function getEmLen( div, str ) {
    var oriInner = div.innerHTML;
    var res;

    div.innerHTML = '<a>'+str+'</a><a>m</a>';

    res = Math.ceil( 100 * (jQuery(div.firstChild).width()) / (jQuery(div.lastChild).width()) ) / 100; 
    //the * 100, / 100 is to remove long trailing divides

    div.innerHTML = oriInner;
    return ''+res+'em';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert px into em. Remember the formula:

```
var em = px / fontSize;
```

So, if you have a `pre` element with the `font-size` set as `1em` which is usually `16px`, and your width in px is say `800px`, then your width in em is `800 / 16` or `50em`. Hope that helps. Vote for my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: It's exactly because you asked me to that I'm not voting for your answer...you answer questions on here to offer help, not to gain rep.